# I cant show data from a WCF in the browser

Tags: asp.net, xml, wcf, xpo

Good morning everyone,

I have a web application project, i've added an xpo model to retrieve data from database and i've added a webservice WCF ( .svc ) to publish data retrieved from the xpo. the problem is when i browse the webservice with google chrome it shows me:

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error

and when i use internal web browser it shows me:

La page XML ne peut pas être affichée 
Impossible d'afficher l'entrée XML en utilisant la feuille de style XSL. Corrigez l'erreur, puis cliquez sur le bouton Actualiser ou réessayez ultérieurement.

---

Nom commencé avec un caractère non valide. Erreur lors du traitement de la ressource

<%@ ServiceHost is underlined.

im working in a group of 3 persons and their data is shown with no porb even we have the same code!

i'm using II8, VS2010, SQL SERVER 2012

heres the content of my .svc file:

namespace DxWCF
{

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class MyWCF : XpoDataServiceV3
{

    public MyWCF() : base(new MyContext("XpoContext", "BaseWCF", CreateDataLayer())) { }
    static IDataLayer CreateDataLayer()
    {
        ConnectionStringSettings mySetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"];
        if (mySetting == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(mySetting.ConnectionString))
            throw new Exception("Fatal error: missing connecting string in web.config file");
        string myconn = mySetting.ConnectionString;

        DevExpress.Xpo.Metadata.XPDictionary dict = new DevExpress.Xpo.Metadata.ReflectionDictionary();
        // Initialize the XPO dictionary. 
        dict.GetDataStoreSchema(typeof(Users).Assembly);
        IDataStore store = XpoDefault.GetConnectionProvider(myconn, DevExpress.Xpo.DB.AutoCreateOption.SchemaAlreadyExists);
        return new ThreadSafeDataLayer(dict, store);
    }
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        config.DataServiceBehavior.AcceptProjectionRequests = true;
    }
}
public class MyContext : XpoContext
{
    public MyContext(string containerName, string namespaceName, IDataLayer dataLayer)
        : base(containerName, namespaceName, dataLayer) { }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: plesae, post your services.svc file

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove space <%@_HERE_IS_EXTRA_SPACE_ServiceHost . . .

Comment: I tried to remove space but no difference, i check my mates code, same code, same errors but their .svc file is published with no probem.

Comment: Since this code works on your collegs pcs, i think the issue is in defenitions. I mean your webservice WCF ( .svc )  file, not implmentation. Review its tags to be opened / closed / formated well.